# Is there an easy way to represent the base64 alphabet in a Python list?

Tags: python, encoding, base64

The alphabet (and its indices) can be found here:

http://www.garykessler.net/library/base64.html

Is there a shorter way than `alphabet = ['A','B',...]` of representing this alphabet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `string` module

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + '+/'
```

Comment: The import more than chews up any gains of not typing it out.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You're right - but it's a bit more modular (which, in this case, I don't need). EDIT: Modular in the sense of rearranging your alphabet if so needed.

Comment: I prefer this answer, but: what about `string.digits` and `"+/"`? Complete would be `alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + "+/"`

Comment: Sure, no problem. And *forgetting something* might also be the problem with the other answer, thus I prefer the `string`-approach

Answer (score 4):

Strings are sequences too.

```
'ABCD...'
```

Comment: Thank you - that's getting smaller. :D